# Crop(cut) image as a paint

Tags: image, crop, bufferedimage, graphics2d, drawimage

As the title i said, i want to cut a region of image (say left bottom corner), but after i cut this area, i want this area to be white as a "Paint" tool to cut image.

I could crop the image by using the code below, but in this code i just put the image where i cut it into a new image file.

```
public Crop() {
  super();

  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:/TEMP/chest.jpg");
  image = icon.getImage();
  image = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(image.getSource(),
    new CropImageFilter(0, 515, 250, 250)));

  ImageIcon icon2= new ImageIcon(image);

  BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(icon2.getIconWidth(),
        icon2.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
  graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

  File newFile = new File("C:/TEMP/chest-new.jpg");
  try {
      ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", newFile);
      } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
     super.paint(g);
     if (insets == null) {
     insets = getInsets();
   }
   g.drawImage(image, insets.left, insets.top, this);
 }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame f = new Crop();
    f.setSize(250, 250);
    f.show();
   }
}
```

What do i want is i want the area that is cut become to "white", and original image.
As a image link below:
[An image after cut](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14562196/1111-cut.jpg)

Comment: `Graphics2D g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();`
`g.setColor(Color.WHITE);`
`g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);`

This is a way to make the image as a cut, but its not actually i wanted. It is not really cut the image.

Comment: You can simply add a white rectangle of specific size at the position you want.

Comment: Yes, this was what i put in the first comment. But i think its not how to cut the image, isn't it?? and this way is not exactly what i want to do.

Comment: What is the difference then, betweenn cutting the image and then coloring the area with white and just replacing the whole area with white rectangle?

Comment: I was thinking the size of the image file will be different.
Cut image size will less than replace the area with white rectangle.

Comment: I just wondering if there any other way i can do this??

Comment: @JarekHuang: Why do you think the file size will differ? Using `g.fillRect()` won't make an extra layer and allow you to get back what was "underneath". It will replace those pixels with the color specified. Using the method in your first comment will produce the effect in your linked image. Go with that. :-)

Comment: @haraldK I was thinking if i do with `g.fillRect()`, and i will not get the original image back (as you said "underneath", but how i can get the exactly original image back after i crop (cut).
Because i need to use original image do some works. Thank you